# How to I set environment variables using gitversion?

Tags: powershell, gitversion

I am trying gitversion /output buildserver in both powershell and command prompt and neither modify the environment variables with GitVersion.SemVer (for example). How can I use it in a script?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/command-line/#output):

> By default GitVersion returns a json object to stdout containing all the variables which GitVersion generates.

So if you want to run it as part of a standalone script rather than a build task, just grab the json output from stdout and convert it to an object:

```
$GitVersion = gitversion |ConvertFrom-Json
$GitVersion.SemVer
```

Comment: do you know if it is possible to set environment variables automatically or do i need to do manually?

Comment: I think you need to set these manually unless you're targeting a build server